# Qt - QGraphicsItem linux - Se pone lento y se degrada con el tiempo

Tags: c++, qt

sigo con mala performance con mis QGraphicsItem en linux sobre una RaspberryPI3B. Entiendo que el problema puede venir aca, en este paint, que cuando recibo un nuevo punto a dibujar en el camino (tracker), vuelve a crear TODO el QPainterPath de nuevo (porque lo genera de forma cubica agregando puntos), entonces cuando los puntos son miles, realmente se pone muy pesado y lento. Los puntos estan guardados en un QVector y en el paint crea un QPainterPath poniendolos de forma cubica, para formar una curva de bezier.

```
void WorkedPathGraph::paint(QPainter *painter, const 
QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *item, QWidget*)
{
    QPen qpen, qpenOld;
    QBrush oldBrush;
    qpen.setColor(QColor("yellow"));

    qpen.setWidth(1);
    qpen.setCosmetic(true);

    qpenOld = painter->pen();
    oldBrush = painter->brush();
    painter->setPen(qpen);

    painter->setClipRect(item->exposedRect);
    painter->setBrush(QColor("yellow"));

    painter->setCompositionMode(QPainter::CompositionMode_SourceOver);
    /************************************************************/
    QPainterPathStroker stroker;
    stroker.setWidth(_anchoLabor);
    stroker.setCapStyle(Qt::FlatCap);
    QPainterPath stroke;

    QPainterPath path2;
    path2.moveTo(points.at(0));

    int i=1;
    const int &maxpoints = points.size();
    while (i + 2 < maxpoints) {
        path2.cubicTo(points.at(i), points.at(i+1), points.at(i+2));
        i += 3;
    }
    while (i < maxpoints) {
        path2.lineTo(points.at(i));
        ++i;
    }

    stroke = stroker.createStroke(path2);

    painter->drawPath(stroke);
    /************************************************************/


    painter->setPen(qpenOld);
    painter->setBrush(oldBrush);
}
```

El problema, se me ocurre a mi, es que cuando hay miles de puntos, los dibuja miles de veces...no hay alguna forma de que sea incremental?, es decir, lo que ya esta dibujado, que no lo vuelva a dibujar. Existe alguna forma de hacer esto con Qt? Gracias mil, me tiene muy procupado esto.
Si hay algo del codigo que no se entiende, me pregunta, porque es parte de un proyecto grande y voy abstrayendo pedazos para poder mostrar aca que es lo que pasa

Comment: Raspberry Pi no es una poderosa maquina asi que en general no vas a obtener un buen rendimiento si usas los qwidgets clásicos, si deseas obtener un rendimiento mayor debes usar la GPU mediante opengl, por ejemplo usa QOpenglWidget, o mejor usa QML que usa nativamente opengl.

Comment: Puede que sea asi, no lo niego. Pero comienza dibujando bien y a medida que se agregan puntos al vector points, se viene abajo el rendimiento. Existe la posibilidad de hacer una parte estatica con Qt y otra dinamica, forma que x ej. solo los ultimos 100 puntos se dibujen dinamicamente y los anteriores esten fijos en una imagen?. Como se podria hacer algo asi? mejoraria la performance?

Comment: Explicame mejor lo siguiente: *solo los ultimos 100 puntos se dibujen dinamicamente y los anteriores esten fijos en una imagen?*

Comment: Hay algunos puntos que no se mueven? , es decir son estaticos para siempre

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78932/discussion-on-question-by-emiliano-torres-qt-qgraphicsitem-linux-se-pone-len).

Comment: @eyllanesc aqui te dejo el enlace a un ejemplo minimo del proyecto. Cualquier duda me avisas. https://github.com/etorresglm/gama

Comment: @EmilianoTorres podrias compartirme el archivo .txt

Comment: @eyllanesc se encuentra en la raiz del proyecto, junto con todos los fuentes

Comment: @EmilianoTorres me distraje con tu descripcion que no lo ví, tu hablaste de miles de puntos pero yo solo veo un icono que se mueve cada cierto tiempo.

Comment: @EmilianoTorres Pero lo malo es que ese unico punto consume un núcleo del Rpi, eso es excesivo, veo que abusas de la memoria dinámica: https://imgur.com/a/GW8uHBx

Comment: @eyllanesc como un unico punto?...no te dibuja un camino amarillo?...si no es asi avisame porque algo quedó mal

Comment: Estos es lo que obtengo despues de unos segundos de ejecucion, no veo nada de lineas amarillas: https://imgur.com/a/eae1Cjl

Comment: Usaste icono para configurar lo que dice el Readme del github?...si no configuras bien eso no vas a ver nada.

Comment: @EmilianoTorres Okay, ya lo configure, veo la linea amarilla, y una malla que se desplaza, ¿por que la malla se desplaza?

Comment: ENTIENDO que la grilla esta fija, lo que se desplaza es la flecha roja. Me tome el trabajo de controlar las curvas y demas detalles respecto a la grilla porque pareciera que se mueve, pero lo que se mueve es la flecha roja y la grilla daria la sensacion de moverse pero creo que no se mueve. Quizas se la pueda poner en una imagen

Comment: @EmilianoTorres Podrias explicarme detalladamente lo que la aplicacion debe hacer, como le dije veo muchas malas prácticas en su codigo, por ejemplo el abuso de la funcion pow() para elevar al cuadrado, el costo de pow(x, 2) es mucho mayor que x*x, voy a tener que mejorar cada clase y para ello necesito mas o menos entender lo que desea hacer, lo que voy entendiendo es que usted quiere graficar cierta ruta que esta en el archivo .txt, hay algo aparte de ello.

Comment: @EmilianoTorres [cont] Otra cosa que veo es que la grilla es un QGraphicsItem, y eso no deberia ser, QGraphicsScene tiene un metodo que se debe sobreescribir que se encarga de pintar el fondo.

Comment: @EmilianoTorres Tambien usa `@eyllanesc` cuando me escribas, asi me notificaran cuando lo hagas.

Comment: @eyllanesc si, es verdad que la grilla es un QGraphicsItem, el tema es que la grilla tiene una medida en metros, porque esta escalada y es muy importante que sea en metros. Si la dibujo en la scene no tengo ese escalonamiento. De todos modos, ahi no esta el cuello de botella. Acabo de correr el programa quitando la parte que pinta y tarde 12 minutos, mientras que si pinta con amarillo, tarda 33 minutos. Claramente el problema esta entre el pintado del camino amarillo

Comment: @EmilianoTorres Si estas midiendo el rendimiento de tu aplicacion mediante el tiempo ¿por que usas un delay: `delay(500);`?, ademas ese delay no es amigable con la GUI.

Comment: @eyllanesc ese delay es para simular el tiempo entre punto y punto que recibo por GPS, como aca lo estoy leyendo de un file, la realidad es que voy a recibir uno cada segundo o .5 segundos. No hace al cuello de botello, solo es para simular que los puntos vienen cada X tiempo.

Comment: @EmilianoTorres, podrias explicarme el algoritmo que utilizas para añadir dibujar la nueva linea en WorkedPathGraph.

Comment: @eyllanesc Tiene dos partes. La del paint son los puntos, puestos en un painterpath y se agregan de forma cubica, el width es lo que el usuario setea en la configuracion como ancho de labor. La otra parte es que por cada punto, se arma un poligono con el punto anterior y el ancho de labor, de forma que se fija con ese poligono si se intersecta con alguno de los que ya fueron armados, si eso pasa quiere decir que ya paso por ahi y es lo que pinta de rojo